# Jetty 9 hosting multiple virtual host with multiple SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I used a ubuntu server 16.04 and jetty 9.3 to deploy multiple virtual host.
Every virtual host has a different domain and a different SSL certificate.
Now only one virtual host with ssl works.
I searched a lot on google and stackoverflow, it says TLS SNI or jetty connectors can do this.But I don't know how to config.

Comment: Are you using the distribution or an embedded form of Jetty? Have you reviewed the documentation on configuring SSL*(https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.20.v20170531/configuring-ssl.html) and on configuring Virtual Hosts (https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.20.v20170531/configuring-virtual-hosts.html)?

* Note there is currently an error in the SNI section of the SSL documentation which refers to the `ExtendedSslContextFactory` class. This class has since been merged into the `SslContextFactory` class. I will be working to resolve this part of the documentation.

Comment: I used distribution jettybase mode deploy.I have reviewed the documentation carefully, thanks for editing jetty document, how to config SNI with SslContextFactory in jetty's xml or ini files?

Comment: There is no special configuration needed for SNI (aside from enabling the `ssl` module in the distribution) - your keystore simply needs to contain multiple certificates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special configuration needed for SNI (aside from enabling the ssl module in the distribution) - your keystore simply needs to contain multiple certificates.

(Copied from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097500/jetty-9-hosting-multiple-virtual-host-with-multiple-ssl-certificate#comment77258091_45097500) because this is the answer)